# Spring MVC and hibernate combining models

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, union

I'm developing a web application using the Spring framework along with Hibernate as the ORM and DAO. I have two Models Class1 and Class2. Which hibernate maps to Database tables Table1 and Table2 respectively. The two tables have similar fields (all Strings) but share no relationship.

```
        Table1                                         Table2
A     B     C     D                               E       F      G
```

I need to display a table in a view that is a consolidated list of all the records in both tables and I need to be able to filter this table by certain criteria.

```
              View
 _________________________________
| Data1   Data2   Data3    Data4  |
|  A        B       C        D    |
|                                 |
|  E       ''       G        H    |
|_________________________________|
```

I haven't had any luck with creating a model that is a combination of the both of them and displaying It's view. I was able to create a separate controller that gets all of the records from both of the models to a single view but the only way I was able to display them was in separate tables. I need the data to be in one table that is sorted by a specific column.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way IMHO, is to create a database view with all you the stuff you need and create a Hibernate entity mapping this view. Use `insertable = false, updatable = false` to map your columns to avoid that anybody tries to update the view using this new Entity.

This way you have to deal with data using SQL instead Hibernate, so I think is easier and can help you to solve the issue.